# Connecting data from 2 data sources to group as one

Tags: r, database, dataframe

I'm currently working with csv's with data about test participants on a diet program.
One CSV has the the partcipants information 'suubject id', chosen group', 'extra calories' etc.

[image]

The second set of csv's are about the different diet groups, meals, calories etc. (of which there are 10)

[image]

My task was to find the total calories of each group then find the total calories of each participants chosen group.

To get the total calories of each group I just made a variable that summed the total calories of each group

```
 one <- sum(groupOne$calories)
```

Then I cleaned the data up a bit in the participants file by removing the 'g' in the row name.

I would ideally like to get some output that has the participants subjectID and their the total calories of their group. Something like below:

```
 |SubjectID||Group||Groups Total Calories|
   1          G3        100cal
   2          G6        200cal
```

After that I'm kind of stuck, I don't quite know how to group the two together to together and spit out some data that matches the participants to the groups to output a clean display of the participants subjectId, their group and the total calories of that group.

Comment: It is probably best to share the output of `dput(df)` than a picture. In addition, if you clearly specify  desired output, a response might be quicker.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I'll try and clean up the question

Comment: There is alot of output in the dput(df) so its kind of hard to copy and paste in

Comment: How do you know which group belong to which meal category?

Comment: I have 10 csv's all different groups. I.e. 'group1.csv' 'group2.csv' etc

Comment: If we focus on the above two tables, is there a column shared between the two?

Comment: No. I inputted the data like this 
group_files <- c("data/Group1.csv",
                 "data/Group2.csv ",
                 "data/Group3.csv ",
                  "data/Group4.csv ",
                  "data/Group5.csv ",
                  "data/Group6.csv ",
                  "data/Group7.csv ",
                  "data/Group8.csv ",
                  "data/Group9.csv ",
                  "data/Group10.csv"
)
participants_file <- read_csv("data/participants.csv")

Comment: and thats where my problem lies as I don't know how to make the connection between the two

Comment: For example,  the information contained within `group1.csv` is about `G1` only?

Comment: Yeh thats true. So something like group1 <- read_csv('group1.csv'). Then group1$Group <- g1 ?? Or would I have to turn it into a dataframe first?

Comment: Yes, make it a character `group1$Group <- "G1"` otherwise it assumes you're trying to replace with an object `g1`. .

Comment: Awesome. Thank you. I'll try that now and report back

Comment: @lbbylun You may also provide `head(dput(dfr))`. Read: [How to make a great R MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/6574038).